# Import python packages in jython

Tags: python, jython

I am unable to import python packages (e.g. numpy) in jython:

```
$ jython

>>> import sys 
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/bin/jython2.5.3/Lib', '__classpath__', '__pyclasspath__/', '/usr/local/bin/jython2.5.3/Lib/site-packages']
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I then tried adding my PYTHONPATH by adding `python.path = /Users/alavin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages` to the Python registry file "/jython2.5.3/registry"...

```
$ jython

>>> import sys 
>>> sys.path
['', '/Users/alavin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/unittest2-0.8.0-py2.7.egg', '/Users/alavin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/argparse-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', '/Users/alavin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/alembic-0.6.7-py2.7.egg', '/Users/alavin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.4-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg', '/Users/alavin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg', '/Users/alavin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages', '/usr/local/bin/jython2.5.3/Lib', '__classpath__', '__pyclasspath__/', '/usr/local/bin/jython2.5.3/Lib/site-packages']
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I'm on a mac osx 10.9. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you have [JyNI](http://jyni.org/)

Comment: You cannot import C extension modules into Jython without something like JyNI, which I think is not yet at the level of supporting numpy

Comment: Indeed Jython does not support numpy and other C extension modules. The support and documentation for JyNI seems lacking, so I've decided to instead use sockets to run python scripts (including modules such as numpy) in my java program. For those looking to use sockets like me, I recommend [this instructional example](http://www.doepiccoding.com/blog/?p=41).